# Unable to test whether a variable is not a string

Tags: php

I am checking if the *ID* input is a not string and not null. Here is the code:

```
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    if(!is_string($id) && !empty($id)) {
        $delete = mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE from users WHERE ID=$id");
        $_SESSION["succMsg"] = "User have been successfully removed";
        Header("Location:login_update.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION["succMsg"] = "Unable to execute the query.";
        Header("Location:login_update.php");
    }
```

It somehow decides to not accept the query that I run. And I have no trouble when I remove the ***if*** statement. Though I want to check beforehand.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @1stthomas  *$_SESSION["succMsg"] = "Unable to execute the query.";*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, that `$_POST["id"];` always is a string - indeed all elements of the `$_POST`-array are - so `is_string($id)` of course returns true. What you *really* mean to do is to check, if it only consists of digits! `ctype_digit($id)` does this for example.

If your purpose is to migitate injection attacks, the easiest would probably be to *cast* it to an integer:

```
$id = (int) $_POST["id"];
```

Then it should work as you expect. The `is_string($id)` is of course unnecessary now. The `is_empty()` check should be performed *before* this assignment now (directly on `$_POST["id"]`). Maybe `isset()` is even more appropriate here, this eliminates for example a warning if `id` wasn't set as a parameter:

```
if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
    $id = (int) $_POST["id"];
    // Do your query....
}
```

Comment: Making the id cast as an *int* was a good idea.It worked.But I always thought it like the PHP would do that like  *id = 23* as no single or double quotes would be included(thats how I know to seperate an int and string value).You learn new things everyday.Thank you @Karim

Comment: @KorayBallı Generally this is true in PHP _code_, but not for POST or GET parameters, those are always transported as type _string_. Yw ;)